# What is correct mimetype with Apache OpenOffice files like (*.odt, *.ods, *.odp)?

Tags: ms-word, mime-types, content-type, opendocument

I  want `*.ods` and `*.odt` files on a website to open in openoffice when clicked, not get saved on desktop, or get opened embedded in a browser etc. Now obviously it all depends on how everything is configured for each user, but what's the best **MIMETYPE** and other settings to achieve just that most of the time?

I know For older `*.doc` documents this was enough:

`header("Content-Type: application/msword")`;

I would like solution for open office.

Comment: This solution can be use in MAC OS too

Answer (score 46, accepted):

My `/etc/mime.types` says it's:

- `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text` for `*.odt`
- `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet` for `*.ods`
- `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation` for `*.odp`

It makes sense, as it's a corporate standard (vnd), designed by OASIS organization, used for different formats of opendocuments.

If you don't want to bother yourself about sending correct mime types, you may use `finfo` class to do it for you:

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
header('Content-Type: ' . $finfo->file('/path/to/file'));
```

Comment: ODS in IIS maps to OleObject - not sure if it's safe to overwrite that but I assume so.